# How do we apply openxlsx formatting when using purrr to output multiple files on multiple tabs?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, openxlsx

I am trying to create formats in excel output files.  In my example, I would like cost 1 and cost 2 to be formatted as dollars and I would like to add the customer to Cell A 1 in the excel output files.  Below is my attempt.  Any tips?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)


df.1 <- tribble(
  ~customer  ,~period, ~cost1, ~cost2 , ~prod,
  'cust1',  '202201', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust1',  '202202', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust1',  '202203', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust1',  '202204', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust2',  '202203', 5, 10,'online',
  'cust2',  '202204', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust2',  '202202', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust3',  '202204', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust4',  '202101', NA, NA, 'online',
  'cust4',  '202102', NA,10, 'online'
  
)


df.1 %>% 
  split(.$customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(df, nm) {
    df %>%
      janitor::remove_empty(which = 'cols') %>% 
      split(.$prod) |> 
      write.xlsx(addStyle(cols = 3:4, rows = 1:nrow(), style = createStyle(numFmt = "0.0%")) ## make cost 1 and cost 2 dollar format
                 ,writeData(paste0('Client Name: ', customer), startCol = 1, startRow = 3) # add the customer to row 1 column 1 , cell A1 in excel
                 ,paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), startRow = 6)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite interesting piece of code. `write.xlsx` is meant for a quick export of a data.frame or list of data.frames to xlsx.

If you require additional formatting or want to add additional data you have  to directly manipulate the workbook object, i.e. both `addStyle` and `writeData` require a workbook object as their first argument.

For that reason in the code below I use the lower level functions to create a workbook, to add the worksheets, to write the data, to apply your desired styles and to finally save the workbook. Doing so requires a second `iwalk` (or ...) where for convenience I make use of a custom function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

export_sheet <- function(wb, customer, data, sheet) {
  addWorksheet(wb, sheet)
  writeData(
    wb,
    paste0("Client Name: ", customer),
    sheet = sheet,
    startCol = 1, startRow = 3
  )
  writeData(wb, data, sheet = sheet, startRow = 6)
  addStyle(wb, sheet,
    cols = 3,
    rows = 6 + seq_len(nrow(data)),
    style = createStyle(numFmt = "0.0%")
  )
  addStyle(wb, sheet,
    cols = 4,
    rows = 6 + seq_len(nrow(data)),
    style = createStyle(numFmt = "0.0%")
  )
}

df.1 %>%
  split(.$customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(df, nm) {
    wb <- createWorkbook()
    df %>%
      janitor::remove_empty(which = "cols") %>%
      split(.$prod) |>
      iwalk(
        ~ export_sheet(wb = wb, customer = nm, data = .x, sheet = .y)
      )

    saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
  })
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help!